# how to solve "Twig\Error\LoaderError" in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, twig

I'm setting twig in my codeigniter folder.

While running the codeigniter application it shows below error,

```
An uncaught Exception was encountered
Type: Twig\Error\LoaderError

Message: Unable to find template "forms/admission.php" (looked into: C:\wamp\www\openApplication\application\views).

Filename: C:\wamp\www\openApplication\application\vendor\twig\twig\src\Loader\FilesystemLoader.php

Line Number: 266

Backtrace:

File: C:\wamp\www\openApplication\application\vendor\twig\twig\src\Loader\FilesystemLoader.php
Line: 161
Function: findTemplate

File: C:\wamp\www\openApplication\application\vendor\twig\twig\src\Environment.php
Line: 351
Function: getCacheKey

File: C:\wamp\www\openApplication\application\vendor\twig\twig\src\Environment.php
Line: 445
Function: getTemplateClass

File: C:\wamp\www\openApplication\application\vendor\twig\twig\src\Environment.php
Line: 423
Function: loadTemplate

File: C:\wamp\www\openApplication\application\vendor\twig\twig\src\Environment.php
Line: 384
Function: load

File: C:\wamp\www\openApplication\application\libraries\Twig.php
Line: 33
Function: render

File: C:\wamp\www\openApplication\application\controllers\Admission.php
Line: 27
Function: render

File: C:\wamp\www\openApplication\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once
```

I want to run twig file format(.twig).

My project code is below,

**Controller Page**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Admission extends CI_Controller {

    /**
     * Index Page for this controller.
     *
     * Maps to the following URL
     *      http://example.com/index.php/welcome
     *  - or -
     *      http://example.com/index.php/welcome/index
     *  - or -
     * Since this controller is set as the default controller in
     * config/routes.php, it's displayed at http://example.com/
     *
     * So any other public methods not prefixed with an underscore will
     * map to /index.php/welcome/<method_name>
     * @see https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html
     */


    public function index()
    {

        $output = "";
        $output .= $this->twig->render('forms/admission');
        $this->output->set_output($output);
    }

}
```

**twig.config**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');


$config['twig']['template_dir'] = VIEWPATH;
$config['twig']['template_ext'] = 'php';
$config['twig']['environment']['autoescape'] = TRUE;
$config['twig']['environment']['cache'] = FALSE;
$config['twig']['environment']['debug'] = FALSE;
```

**MY_Loder.php**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class MY_Loader extends CI_Loader {
    public function view($template, $data = array(), $return = FALSE) {
        $CI =& get_instance();

        try {
            $output = $CI->twig->render($template, $data);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            show_error(htmlspecialchars_decode($e->getMessage()), 500, 'Twig Exception');
        }

        // Return the output if the return value is TRUE.
        if ($return === TRUE) {
            return $output;
        }

        // Otherwise append to output just like a view.
        $CI->output->append_output($output);
    }
}
```

**config/autoload.php**

> $autoload['libraries'] = array('twig');
>
> $autoload['config'] = array('twig');

**config/config.php**

> $config['composer_autoload'] = TRUE;

If any mistake are there in my coding.

Comment: Whats the value of `VIEWPATH`? Is this a constant you've defined? This should point to the folder in which you store the templates

Comment: I didnot set any value in VIEWPATH. How to set this value and where ?

Comment: Just change `VIEWPATH` to the location of your folder then, e.g. `$config['twig']['template_dir']  = __DIR__ . '/../path/to/folder';`

Comment: viewpath is a constant in codeigniter that points to `application/views`

Comment: Now my problem is solved. Thanks for your kind attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In below config file I use php as file extension. like

> $config['twig']['template_ext'] = 'php';

Insteed of 'php' I use 'twig' option to overcome this problem.

> $config['twig']['template_ext'] = 'twig';

Now my .twig extention file is working fine.